# Grand total of accounts SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a student this is homework...  I have one table with four columns: Accounts(numbers), balances(money), and two for descriptions. I have to get a grand total of the balances... This VIEW shows the sums of the balance column but I need to total the sums, also.  Any help pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated.

```
CREATE VIEW [account_balance_sums]

AS
    SELECT SUM(balance) AS total,
           SUBSTRING(Account,0,2) AS account_group,


      FROM COA

  GROUP BY account_group

GO

SELECT * FROM [account_balance_sums]
```

Comment: That's not going to give you a sum per the substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try totaling them the same way the view creates a total for each account, by using SUM?

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM COA
```

(Just don't `GROUP BY`, so that you get a full total instead of just a per-accountgroup total.)

Alternatively, you could sum the account totals returned from the view:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM [account_balance_sums]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want the total of all balances?

```
SELECT Sum(Balances)
FROM COA
```

Additionally your `VIEW` will not work as you cannot have an alias in a `GROUP BY` clause..

Edit after comment...

I'm not sure whether the question implies that the grand total should be a part of the view, also is your account number column numeric? As SUBSTRING will not work.

```
CREATE VIEW viewAccount_Balance_Sums
AS 
SELECT SUM(Balance) as Total, LEFT(Account,2) AS Account_group
FROM  COA
GROUP BY LEFT(Account,2)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Balance), 'Grand Total'
FROM COA
```

Comment: Create and display a VIEW that displays the account balance subtotals for each account group.  Account group is defined as the first two digits of the account number.  Display a grand total of the balance column at the end of the display.

Comment: I've edited the post, but the question isn't clear whether they are two separate queries or the output from the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SUM in conjunction with the view in a query.

Comment: N.B. - was assuming that the view shouldn't be modified, and needed to be used in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(balance) AS total, SUBSTRING(Account,0,2) AS account_group 
FROM COA    
GROUP BY account_group wirh rollup
```